# ASP.NET MVC 3, Entity Framework, Stored Procedures and Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, stored-procedures, entity-framework-4, validation, poco

I am an ASP.NET Web Forms developer. My manager has just decided that all future projects will be developed using ASP.NET MVC and so I have a lot to learn very quickly it seems!

All our data operations are handled via stored procedures that are written by an in-house DBA and we are going to use EF. I have used EF to handle this scenario before in a Web Forms project and it was OK. I generated complex types for the SP results and I handled validation using Web Forms Validation controls.

The ASP.NET MVC 3 tutorials and guides I have been reading use EF Code First and use Data Annotations to handle the validation and it all looks really nice but I do not have that luxury. I had a look at some Database First guides but they were not focused on the exclusive use of stored procedures and were not very helpful.

My main concern is that I do not want to write server and client side validation logic if I can avoid it. I keep seeing a lot of discussion about POCO classes too but I am not really sure if they fit for this scenario or if they are a "Code First thing".

I am about to start my first project using ASP.NET MVC 3 and I have a couple of questions.

Is there a way I can use Data Annotations to handle my client and server side validation, and if not, what is my best alternative?

Are POCO classes useful/relevant when using EF in this manner?

Can anyone point me in the direction of a good tutorial/guide and/or give me some advice please?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use EF with MVC.  That's just the most common scenario.  If you're going to use EF then you will probably benefit more from using EF (with ObjectContext, rather than DbContext) and a DatabaseFirst approach.  Your database first approach will just drag and drop all the stored procedures into the designer and then generate an object context with stored procs.  You don't need POCO's because you're not dealing with entities.

You do need Data Transfer objects.  EF will generate the return results for you (although there are cases where EF gets confused and you need to help it).  It will generate the methods that call the queries and parameters to pass to the query.

If you choose not to use EF, then you can use plain old ADO.NET and create a data access layer, or you can use something like the Enterprise Framework Data Access Application Blocks.

The key thing is that even though the tutorials all use EF, you don't have to.  You can use whatever technology you want.  MVC is data agnostic.

Comment: +1 we don't use EF either, strictly a DAL generated that contains DAAB code and DTOs and all DB work is handled by DBA. All I have to do is call the correct CRUD method from my BLL entity

Comment: Thanks for the answer and comment. So could I just decorate my BLL classes with validation annotations and my client and server side validation would be handled?

Comment: That's the consensus.. there is an addin that, if you decorate your BLLs with annotations you can map those to ViewModels and those rules will be translated and available in the model, called AutoMapper. I've never used it personally tho

Answer (score 0):

generlly , data annotations + jquery.validate is enough ,if not , you can try DataAnnotaions.Extensions , if you prefer to keep validation logic and POCO class seperated , FluentValidation is a good choice .

tutorials:

```
 http://www.asp.net/mvc
 search mvcmusicstore  at codeplex.com
 search nerddinner at codeplex.com
```